# How to encrypt and decrypt strings longer than 65535 characters with PHP

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, php-openssl, synology

Here is my problem,

I want to encrypt JSON files that may be very long in some cases. (Sometimes containing images in Base64 format).

On the following test servers, everything works:

- Raspberry Pi 3
- Dell Poweredge T110
- IIS on Windows 10
- Synology DS1815 +

On the other hand, on the following servers, (Which are intended to be used..) the encryption does not work with more than 65535 characters, the server seems to crash.

- Synology RS212
- Synology DS112 +

Is there a restriction on the CPU?

Can a parameter of php.ini affect?

I tested exactly the same code on multiple servers, and on both Synology mentioned, it does not work ...

Here is my class of encryption / decryption:

```
class PHP_AES_Cipher {

    private static $OPENSSL_CIPHER_NAME = "AES-256-CBC"; //Name of OpenSSL Cipher 
    private static $CIPHER_KEY_LEN = 32; 

    static function encrypt($key, $iv, $data) {
        if (strlen($key) < PHP_AES_Cipher::$CIPHER_KEY_LEN) {
            $key = str_pad("$key", PHP_AES_Cipher::$CIPHER_KEY_LEN, "0");
        } else if (strlen($key) > PHP_AES_Cipher::$CIPHER_KEY_LEN) {
            $key = substr($str, 0, PHP_AES_Cipher::$CIPHER_KEY_LEN); 
        }

        $encodedEncryptedData = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($data, PHP_AES_Cipher::$OPENSSL_CIPHER_NAME, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
        $encodedIV = base64_encode($iv);
        $encryptedPayload = $encodedEncryptedData.":".$encodedIV;

        return $encryptedPayload;

    }


    static function decrypt($key, $data) {
        if (strlen($key) < PHP_AES_Cipher::$CIPHER_KEY_LEN) {
            $key = str_pad("$key", PHP_AES_Cipher::$CIPHER_KEY_LEN, "0");
        } else if (strlen($key) > PHP_AES_Cipher::$CIPHER_KEY_LEN) {
            $key = substr($str, 0, PHP_AES_Cipher::$CIPHER_KEY_LEN);
        }

        $parts = explode(':', $data); //Separate Encrypted data from iv.
        $decryptedData = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($parts[0]), PHP_AES_Cipher::$OPENSSL_CIPHER_NAME, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, base64_decode($parts[1]));

        return $decryptedData;
    }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
$data = PHP_AES_Cipher::encrypt($key, $iv, $data);
```

and

```
$data = PHP_AES_Cipher::decrypt($key, $iv, $data);
```

Assuming everything works on some servers, I think the code has no problems. I already checked the Apache and PHP logs, nothing to report.

I have been searching for days without understanding the cause of the problem.

In hope that someone can help me :-)

Comment: Please don't write your own encryption library, use a library like [Libsodium](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/00-intro.md)

Comment: Are the PHP and openssl versions the same?

Comment: @Mehdi Okay, I'll do it, but that does not answer my question :S

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yes, on the DS1815 + (which works) and the DS112 + (which does not work) I have exactly the same version of PHP, OpenSSL and Apache. It's installed from the Synology Package Manager

Comment: The problem I had is on large Files, I started having out of memory issues encrypting the whole file at once.  I posed my solution to that, not sure if it's the same problem, but its to much to explain in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chunk it,

This is what I do (Uses PHPSecLib2 )

```
/**
 * AES encrypt large files using streams and chunking
 * 
 * @param resource $stream
 * @param resource $outputStream
 * @param string $key
 * @throws SecExecption
 */
function streamSymEncode($stream, &$outputStream, $key, $chunkSize = 10240){
    if(!is_resource($stream)) throw new Execption('Resource expected[input]');  
    rewind($stream); //make sure the stream is rewound

    if(!is_resource($outputStream)) throw new Execption('Resource expected[output]');

    $Cipher = new AES(AES::MODE_CBC);
    $Cipher->setKey($key);
    //create the IV
    $iv = Random::string($Cipher->getBlockLength() >> 3);
    $Cipher->setIV($iv);

    if(strlen($iv_base64 = rtrim(base64_encode($iv), '=')) != 22) throw new Execption('IV lenght check fail');

    fwrite($outputStream, $iv_base64.'$'); //add the IV for later use when we decrypt

    while(!feof($stream)){
        $chunk = fread($stream, $chunkSize); 
        fwrite($outputStream, rtrim(base64_encode($Cipher->encrypt($chunk)),'=').':');
    }

    $stat = fstat($outputStream);

    ftruncate($outputStream, $stat['size'] - 1);    //trim off the last character, hanging ':'    
}

/**
 * AES decrypt large files that were previously encrypted using streams and chunking 
 * 
 * @param resource $stream
 * @param resource $outputStream
 * @param string $key
 * @throws SecExecption
 */
function streamSymDecode($stream, &$outputStream, $key){
    if(!is_resource($stream)) throw new Execption('Resource expected[input]');
    rewind($stream); //make sure the stream is rewound

    if(!is_resource($outputStream)) throw new Execption('Resource expected[output]');

    $Cipher = new AES(AES::MODE_CBC);
    $Cipher->setKey($key);

    $iv = base64_decode(fread($stream, 22) . '==');
    $Cipher->setIV($iv);

    fread($stream, 1); //advance 1 for the $

    $readLine = function(&$stream){
        $line = '';
        while(false !== ($char = fgetc($stream))){
            if($char == ':') break;
            $line .= $char;
        }
        return $line;
    };

    while(!feof($stream)){
        $chunk = $readLine($stream);

        $decrypted = $Cipher->decrypt(base64_decode($chunk.'=='));
        if(!$decrypted) throw new Execption('Failed to decode!');

        fwrite($outputStream, $decrypted);
    }       
}
```

It takes two File stream resources like what you get from `fopen` and a key. Then it uses the same ecryption but chunks the file into `$chunkSize` separates them with `:` and when it decodes, it splits it back into chunks and re-assembles everything.

It winds up like this (for example)

```
  IV$firstChunk:secondChunk:thirdChunk
```

This way you don't run out of memory trying to encrypt large files.

Please Note this was part of a lager class I use so I had to trim some things and make a few changes, that I haven't tested.

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib

Cheers.

Comment: Wow, that seems like a good solution! I will try this as soon as possible!

Comment: In fact I do not think it will work in my case because I have to decrypt in Android in JAVA ...

Comment: Well if you can write (control) the decryption code, it will work.  You'll just have to port it to JAVA

Comment: Well, that's right. I'm going to try ! But your solution works and answer my question! Thank you for helping me once again!